# Array with single element of type string "magically" turning into string

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, types

Not sure why this is happening.   At this point in my code these array may have a single element.

```
actualAnswer = actualAnswer.split(" ");
playerAnswer = playerAnswer.split(" ");
```

I then pass them through this function.

```
     function checkForPlural(playerAnswer, actualAnswer){

var answerObject = {playerAnswer: playerAnswer,
                    actualAnswer: actualAnswer};

for (var answerWord in actualAnswer){
    if (actualAnswer[answerWord].slice(-1) == "S")
    {
            answerObject.actualAnswer[answerWord] = actualAnswer[answerWord].substring(0, actualAnswer[answerWord].length - 1);
    }
}
for (var answerWord in playerAnswer){
    if (playerAnswer[answerWord].slice(-1) == "S")
    {
            answerObject.playerAnswer[answerWord] = playerAnswer[answerWord].substring(0, playerAnswer[answerWord].length - 1);
    }
}
}
```

When I return the object IF the array's passed in only had a single element javascript decides to interpret them as a string so if I were to use answerObject.actualAnswer.length it'll give me the length of the string, rather than just 1.

Here is the plunker, unfortunately/fortunately it seems to work as intended on there so i'm confused:
https://plnkr.co/edit/nIqq3VdjjMa2GDWyqkxx

EDIT: The problem was at an earlier junction in my code, sorry!

Comment: What is purpose of creating objects and using `for..in` loop where you have passed arrays to the function?

Comment: @guest271314 I guess I could have returned the arrays straight up.  I just thought i'd stuff em in an object and extract the arrays again for...reasons.  I'm not sure it's madness!  Either way I would or been returning an object or a multi-dimensional array though no?

Comment: What is expected result? If the last letter in the string is `"S"` return string up to last `"S"`?

Comment: The expected result is to have an object with two arrays in it.  Instead if the arrays passed in have one element the object returned has two strings inside.

Comment: What is purpose of `for..in` loop and `if` condition?

Comment: the purpose of the function is to determine if the strings in the arrays end with a s. If any of them do i chop the s off the end of string.

Comment: That is what was attempting to verify at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45559052/array-with-single-element-of-type-string-magically-turning-into-string#comment78077681_45559052

Comment: Can you get a working plunker with the issue you are trying to describe?

Comment: @KaranDesai added to my post

Comment: Yes it is working in plunker

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.map()` to return a new array, `String.prototype.replace()` to, if exists, replace the ending `"S"` character in a string, return an object having properties set to the function parameter identifiers

```js
const regexp = /S$/;
const re = "";

function parseAnswer(arr, regexp_, re_) {
  return arr.map(function(prop) {return prop.replace(regexp_, re_)})
}

function checkForPlural(playerAnswer, actualAnswer) {
  return {
    playerAnswer: parseAnswer(playerAnswer, regexp, re),
    actualAnswer: parseAnswer(actualAnswer, regexp, re)
  }
}

console.log(checkForPlural("abc defS ghi".split(" "), "12S 456 78S".split(" ")))
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in question is working correctly, the "magic" conversion was because of an error in another function that was overwriting the array with a string.  My bad.